# Segmentation fault 11 using arrays

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I am a beginner with coding and I got my code to compile but when I input integers, I get segmentation fault. Please help.

The problem is: I need to first get how many students there are then the next inputs will be the marks of those students. So if inputed 3, the next inputs should be 3 marks of the 3 students. Then the input should be either g(girl) or b(boy). From there, if boy, I need to sum up all the odd marks.

THIS IS MY CODE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int marks_summation(int* marks, int number_of_students, char gender){

    int i=0, sum=0;
    int marksforGirls=0, marksforBoys=0;
    char g;

    for(marks = 0; *marks <= number_of_students; marks++){
        if(gender == g){
            do{
                if(marks[i]%2 == 0){
                    marksforGirls = marks[i];
                    i++;
                    sum += marksforGirls;
                }
            } while(*marks<=number_of_students);
        }
        else{
            do{
                if(marks[i]%2 != 0){
                    marksforBoys = marks[i];
                    i++;
                    sum += marksforBoys;
                }
            } while (*marks<=number_of_students);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){

    int i=0, number_of_students=0;
    int *marks=0;
    int sum=0;
    char gender;

    scanf("%d",&number_of_students);

    marks = (int*)malloc(number_of_students * sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<number_of_students; i++){
        scanf(" %d", &marks[i]);//for every marks put in, it will go into marks
    }

    scanf("%c",&gender);

    marks_summation(marks, number_of_students, gender);

    printf("%d", sum);

    free(marks);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for(marks=0; *marks <= …` directly crashes. You probably meant `for(*marks=0; ...`!?

Comment: Fyi, turn up your warnings. Look at `marks_summation`, specifically at `if(gender == g)` and ask yourself, "What is the value of `g` when this is checked?" if the answer is anything other than "I don't know", it's wrong. Evaluation of indeterminate variables invokes *undefined behavior*. From what I see, `g` is *never* set, and never even *used* in that function other than the improper usage I already mentioned, so consider it fair game for removal. That function also accumulates `sum`, and does absolutely nothing with it.

Comment: @WhozCraig maybe it was meant be 'g', ignoring the declaration...

Comment: You have an unnecessary space in front of `%d` but lack the necessary space in front of `%c`. You must also check the function return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @sstefan i seriously doubt it, but i give us a one-in-five chance the OP actually clarifies the matter further. If anything, it would be checked for `f` and/or `m` . (at least in the world I live in). If ever there was a need for a conversation with ones [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) that function is it.

Answer (score 0):

The following line is not doing what you might think it does:

```
for(marks = 0; *marks <= number_of_students; marks++)
```

I believe you'd want to use an index to access each of marks elements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the problem is in the for loop. Besides pointers being wrong, your loop condition is also wrong. Furthermore your function doesn't return anything. Also, both of your do-while loops are infinite loops.

Try this:

```
int mark_sum(int *marks, int number_of_students, char gender){
  int sum = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < number_of_students; ++i){
    if(gender = 'g'){
      if(marks[i] % 2 == 0)
        sum += marks[i];
    } else {
      if(marks[i] % 2 != 0)
        sum += marks[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Also, in main you need to actually store the value returned by the function:

```
int sum = mark_sum(marks, number_of_students, gender);
```